# Not being assigned an IP address

Tags: networking, internet, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm having a hard time trying to get a XP laptop online. 
Whether I use either wifi or ethernet I get the same result. It tries to get an ip but times out and just stays connected with limited funtionality

The network is fine. It has several computers connected to it fine. 
I've checked the router to see if maybe its filtering its MAC address(s) but no.
I've checked for static IP settings in the adapter TCP\IP settings but it's all on DHCP.
Have removed all anti virus\firewall software, even used removal tools such as the Norton Removal Tool.
Reinstalled drivers, updated drivers.
Run winsock fix
Checked services (DHCP, DNS, etc)

Running out of ideas now :(

Comment: Have you tried giving it a static IP in your network and ping it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, doesn't work though. Definitely setting that up right because I have some computers on the network with static addresses

Comment: The router is also the DHCP server?  What is the range of IP's available to the DHCP server?  Can you reboot the DHCP server and try again?  Also, do you have a bridge defined in the XP configuration?

Comment: You might consider trying out this laptop on another network for debugging. Have you checked that the `DHCP Client` service is running properly (can be checked in `services.msc`)?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention having tried this, so here goes: from the command line, enter these commands:

**ipconfig /release**
**ipconfig /renew**

Comment: Sorry yes that is one I tried but no luck with that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I would burn and boot up a linux live cd (Ubuntu's is nice), and try to connect over the wired connection. If this works, then there is something screwy with the OS. If not, you've ruled out any software issue on that machine.